# Change font size on hover move other divs

Tags: html, css

I wanted to change fonts size on hover on  elements, the prolem I've encountered is that when i move on an  item the other divs of the list move down. This is my code:

**CSS**

```
a{
    /* position:absolute */
    font-size:16px;
}

a:hover {
    color:#0033CC;
    font-size:18px;
}

#menu_list{
    width:859px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }

#menu_list li{
    width:130px;
    height:21px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border:1px solid #616261; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family:sans-serif, arial, helvetica; 
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    font-weight:bold; 
    text-align: center; 
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu_list">
    <li><a>look</a></li>
    <li><a>look</a></li>
    <li><a>look</a></li>
    <li><a>look</a></li>
    <li><a>look</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gracedescending/KLk4w/).

As you can see I wrote position:absolute for the  element, that works, meaning that the divs stay still, but i can't figure out how to center my text if I do so. I guessed the problem was that the  element didn't have top margin, so I tried that too but i guess for inline element it's impossible to set margins, or maybe I just don't now the right way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should give a `line-height` to the outermost inline elements (in your example that's the `<li>`) at least equal to the biggest size the inner elements are going to be (on hover).

Additionally, you should also give `vertical-align: middle` to the inner elements (the anchors); without it their bottom edges are aligned, producing the jarring visual.

There is no need for `position: absolute`.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/2nWDm/)**.

Comment: Thank you, I choose this one as right answer because of the explanation and for the bonus vertical-align.

Answer (score 0):

Change `height:21px` into `line-height` and decrease the `line-height by 1px` on `hover`

```
a:hover {
    color:#0033CC;
    font-size:18px; line-height:20px;
    }
#menu_list li{
    width:130px;
    line-height:21px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border:1px solid #616261; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family:sans-serif, arial, helvetica; 
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    font-weight:bold; 
    text-align: center; 
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KLk4w/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float:left` to the `<li>` and you will have no problems at all with the move of other div.

```
#menu_list li{

    float:left

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also assign `position: relative` to the `li` and change the `a` like this:

```
a {
    position:absolute;
    font-size:16px;
    display: block;
    width: 130px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

It's not the most elegant solution possible (which should be the `line-height` one), but it works.

Comment: I was trying to go that way but I felt too that it was not a great solution.